# get value on google spreadsheet API with PHP

Tags: php, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have been trying to get a single value on google spreadsheet for my school project .Since I am still new in PHP script ,I follow the google guideline which is this link [google guidelines](https://developers.google.com/sheets/guides/concepts) .But I cannot find any documentation about getting value on the sheet based on my input .

I plan to use another program to input a single string value and will check whether the value exist on the spreadsheet or not . If yes it will be shown .

I am still quite new in programming with PHP so a code example/simple explanation will be nice . Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You should try the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/quickstart/php) for PHP. It is correct to read about the document to be familiar with the terms, request and response forms and all the basic stuff about the API. In the quickstart, you will be learning the code implementation of the API starting with the basic function like, listing (`getValues()`).

Here is a snippet from the quickstart :

```
// Prints the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
// https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
$spreadsheetId = '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms';
$range = 'Class Data!A2:E';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();

if (count($values) == 0) {
print "No data found.\n";
} else {
print "Name, Major:\n";
foreach ($values as $row) {
// Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
printf("%s, %s\n", $row[0], $row[4]);
}
}
```

Hope this helps.